# CVRPTW, hard constraints is broken even when there is unused vehicles

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to use optaplanner VRP in my project but I am stuck with the below.

```
01:39:30.070 [main        ] DEBUG     CH step (3), time spent (807), score (-29init/-351hard/-25749soft), selected move count (36), picked move ( latitude=42.892975, longitude=-78.877032}, demand=100.3} {TimedWindowedVehicle{Weight=350/ null, Volume=16 /null , Orders =0}}).
01:39:30.172 [main        ] DEBUG     CH step (4), time spent (909), score (-28init/-652hard/-31285soft), selected move count (37), picked move ( latitude=42.885502, longitude=-78.785842}, demand=300.8} {TimedWindowedVehicle{Weight=350/ null, Volume=16 /null , Orders =0}}).
01:39:30.259 [main        ] DEBUG     CH step (5), time spent (996), score (-27init/-654hard/-35321soft), selected move count (38), picked move (latitude=42.917089, longitude=-78.857812}, demand=2.09} {   latitude=42.892975, longitude=-78.877032}, demand=100.3}}).
01:39:30.352 [main        ] DEBUG     CH step (6), time spent (1089), score (-26init/-656hard/-38788soft), selected move count (39), picked move ( latitude=42.85082, longitude=-78.802339}, demand=1.65} { latitude=42.885502, longitude=-78.785842}, demand=300.8}}).
01:39:30.431 [main        ] DEBUG     CH step (7), time spent (1168), score (-25init/-658hard/-40532soft), selected move count (40), picked move (latitude=42.907763, longitude=-78.792994}, demand=2.05} {null -> TimedWindowedVehicle{Weight=350/ null, Volume=16 /null , Orders =0}}).
```

In my solution, there are 50 vehicles on the vehicle list. But When I am running the example Optaplaaner is breaking the hard constraint on vehicle capacity and only using 4 vehicles whereas there are other unused vehicles in the solution. Just wondering if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The score is `-25init/-658hard/-40532soft`, which contains `-25init`, which means the Construction Heuristic hasn't finished yet (after only 1168 milliseconds, not surprising) and 25 visits remain unassigned.
That doesn't explain why it breaks 658 hard constraints and yet you say to have unassigned vehicles.

First run `System.out.println(scoreManager.create(solverFactory).getSummary(yourSolution));` to figure out which hard constraitns are broken and by which entities.

Second, presume that visit A is 3 hours of driving time away from the neareast depot, the depots open at 8:00 and A's dueTime is 10:00 (and readyTime 9:00, so a time window from 9 till 10 AM). Regardless of the number of vehicles available, is it possible not to break hard constraints?

Comment: `Explanation of score (-322hard/-8158563soft):
    Constraint match totals:
        -289hard: constraint (vehicleCapacity) has 1 matches:
            -289hard: justifications ([TimedWindowedVehicle-0{Weight=350/ 422.49, Volume=16 /19 , Orders =10/25}, 639.90])`  
Above is the explanation of the score which seems correct. What I am not understanding is, Vehicle list is having another unassigned vehicle (all with same TW). 
I have play around with the examples and all worked as expected, Maybe I am missing something in my custom example, which I am not able to figure out so far.

Comment: This is working fine, I had defined the wrong constraints. Thanks Geoffrey.